# SSRS form parameter passing: input type submit vs. image

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I need to use an image to submit a form that contains the SSRS parameters that get passed into the report.

Is there any way to get SSRS to **not** take "input type=image..." as a parameter along with all the "input type=hidden...' ones it greedly sucks in?  Instead of this:

input type="submit" value="Submit"

I'm trying:

input type="image" src="someimagepath.png"

The first work's just fine, but the latter causes SSRS to crater and complain bitterly about an undefined parameter x being passed.

Thx

Comment: `input type="image"` isn't valid last time I checked, it won't do what you're thinking.

Comment: why do you think <input type="image" is no longer valid?  W3C still lists it as valid, and states its function as being to provide a graphical submit, which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find around this problem:  create 2 hidden SSRS report parameters named "x" and "y".  Check "Allow null value" and "Hidden" properties on.

The problem seems to be that SSRS looks for a name="submit" and ignores it. So regular onld type="submit" gets by that way.

However, type=image POSTs as "name.x" and "name.y".  I tried name="submit" and got "submit.x" and "submit.y", but still SSRS persisted in thinking these to be passed parameters.  I tried id="submit".  Still no joy.

It appears SSRS is not smart enough to see incoming type="image" parameters without some help.  Now in fairness to SSRS, I suppose there are some reports where knowing the moouse position can help figure out what to do in the report.  But still, forcing every report to have 2 useless parameters seems a wee bit obtuse.